# Office-JS Outlook add-in enter forward mode

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am new to Outlook add-in development. I want to automate a simple process; selecting an e-mail and clicking on a button "Forward" inside my add-in which makes the e-mail enter Forward mode (replicating the functionality of the Forward button in Outlook) and adding a recipient that I specify in my code. The desired function should look like this, but of course this is not working:

```
export async function forwardMail(){
   var item = Office.context.mailbox.item; //=the email
   item.Forward();
   item.addRecipient("my-email-address@outlook.com");
}
```

And like mentioned, this function should simply enter the Forward mode in the Outlook application and add my recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Office web add-ins are working under the current item in Outlook only:

> I want to automate a simple process; selecting an e-mail and clicking on a button "Forward" inside my add-in which makes the e-mail enter Forward mode

You can do the required modifications using OfficeJS or EWS, Outlook REST API or MS Graph API. For example, once you have a token and the message's id, you call into Microsoft Graph `/forward` endpoint:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}/forward
Content-type: application/json

{
  "comment": "",
  "toRecipients": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "name": "recipient-name",
        "address": "recipient-email"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the first step. I am now stuck at acquiring the token. According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api), I can get the access token through the `getCallbackTokenAsync` method. However, passing this token into the MS Graph `/forward` endpoint does not work. It seems to be the incorrect token. When I try using the token acquired with the `getCallbackTokenAsync` method with the Outlook REST API, it does work, but how do we make it work with the MS Graph API?

Comment: To use MS Graph, your add-ins requires SSO. See the instructions here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph